# Using updated values in a SQL trigger

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to make a simple trigger that updates a customer balance when a payment is made.  The error is shown right after the begin statement.  I'm trying to use the new inserted customerID in the where statement and again a few lines down to calculate a new balance.  Can someone help me with the correct syntax?  Tables are at the bottom.

```
--Whenever a payment is made, customer amount owed is adjusted
create or replace trigger paymentUpdate
after insert on payment
for each row
when (new.transactionID > 0)

declare
newAmount decimal(7,2);
currentBalance decimal(7,2);

begin
--Get the outstanding customer balance
select amountOwed into currentBalance
from customer
where customer.customerID=:new.customerID; --Does this do what I think it does?
-- ^^is any of this needed?

--Subtracts the recently made payment from the customer balance
newAmount := currentBalance - :new.amount;

--Update customer amount owed
update customer.amountOwed
set amountOwed = newAmount
where customer.customerID=:new.customerID;
dbms_output.put_line('Original account balance was: '||currentBalance);
dbms_output.put_line('Payment made was: $'||:new.amount); --Check this
dbms_output.put_line('Customer account balance is now: '||newAmount);

end paymentUpdate;
/
--commit needed?
```

TABLES:

```
INSERT INTO customer (customerID, name, address, insurance, contactInfo, customerType, licenseNumber, amountOwed)
VALUES (45124512, 'Bob Jones',  '232 Sycamore Ln.', 'Pekin', 3095555145, 'New', 'SSSSFFFYYDDD', 220.00);
INSERT INTO customer (customerID, name, address, insurance, contactinfo, customertype, licensenumber, amountOwed)
VALUES (12892222, 'Mike Tyson','100 Haters Rd.', 'Progressive', 2175555555, 'Regular', 'FGHJHHHHTYYY', 42.00);

INSERT INTO payment (customerID, transactionID, amount, method, payDate)
VALUES (45124512, 56785678, 220.00, 'Credit Card', '25-JUN-15');    
INSERT INTO payment (customerID, transactionID, amount, method, payDate)
VALUES (12892222, 68689000, 42.00, 'Cash', '25-JUN-15');
```

ERRORS:
7/1 PL/SQL: SQL STATEMENT IGNORED
9/6 PL/SQL: ORA-00942 table or view does not exist
16/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
16/17 PL/SQL: ORA-00942 table or view does not exist

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error you're seeing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creation of trigger block, another small change, in the update statement its just table name, not tablename.column name

```
SQL> create or replace trigger paymentUpdate
  2  after insert on payment
  3  for each row
  4  when (new.transactionID > 0)
  5
  6  declare
  7  newAmount decimal(7,2);
  8  currentBalance decimal(7,2);
  9
 10  begin
 11  --Get the outstanding customer balance
 12  select amountOwed into currentBalance
 13  from customer
 14  where customerID=:new.customerID;
 15
 16
 17  newAmount := currentBalance - :new.amount;
 18
 19
 20  update customer   -- corrected from your code
 21  set amountOwed = newAmount
 22  where customerID=:new.customerID;
 23  dbms_output.put_line('Original account balance was: '||currentBalance);
 24  dbms_output.put_line('Payment made was: $'||:new.amount); --Check this
 25  dbms_output.put_line('Customer account balance is now: '||newAmount);
 26
 27  end paymentUpdate;
 28  /

Trigger created.
```

Initial data before inserting new payment

```
SQL> select  * from payment;

CUSTOMERID TRANSACTIONID     AMOUNT METHOD               PAYDATE
---------- ------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------
  45124512      56785678        220 Credit Card          25-JUN-15
  12892222      68689000         42 Cash                 25-JUN-15

SQL> select * from customer;

CUSTOMERID NAME                 ADDRESS                                  INSURANCE            CONTACTINFO CUSTOMERTYPE         LICENSENUMBER        AMOUNTOWED
---------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
  45124512 Bob Jones            232 Sycamore Ln.                         Pekin                 3095555145 New                  SSSSFFFYYDDD                220
  12892222 Mike Tyson           100 Haters Rd.                           Progressive           2175555555 Regular              FGHJHHHHTYYY                 42
```

After inserting a new payment for customer and the trigger being fired.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO payment (customerID, transactionID, amount, method, payDate)
  2  VALUES (45124512, 56785679, 50, 'Credit Card', '26-JUN-15');
Original account balance was: 220
Payment made was: $50
Customer account balance is now: 170

1 row created.
```

The amount due has now been reduced according to the trigger, it was 220 earlier and after a payment of 50, the amountowed is now 170.

```
SQL> select * from customer;

CUSTOMERID NAME                 ADDRESS                                  INSURANCE            CONTACTINFO CUSTOMERTYPE         LICENSENUMBER        AMOUNTOWED
---------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
  45124512 Bob Jones            232 Sycamore Ln.                         Pekin                 3095555145 New                  SSSSFFFYYDDD                170
  12892222 Mike Tyson           100 Haters Rd.                           Progressive           2175555555 Regular              FGHJHHHHTYYY                 42

SQL>
```